# HUGE model in rails? What would be the appropriate way to do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm practicing, and came up with an idea that I should create an experiment that involves building an editor that can customize a real car with all parts that a real car can have. And then allow the user to individually customize it down to the finest level of detail **simply using true or false** And then output it accordingly like:

```
<%= if @vehicle.steering_wheel_color == blue %>
  show a blue steeringhweel
<% end %>

<%= if @vehicle.steering_wheel_color == red %>
  show a red steeringhweel
<% end %>

<%= if @vehicle.gear_box_knob == brown_wood %>
  show a brown wooden gear knob
<% end %>
```

Since we're talking roughly around 500-1000 parameters(?) I'm sure that my idea of Architecture is preeeetty bad, so I'm wondering what the 'correct' or even the **best way** of doing it would be? considering that each variable needs to be queryable?

I've done some googling and I found one answer that advised to do one model that belongs to vehicle that houses all the booleans. But then I asked a friend and he said that would be a terrible idea.

I guess my question is, what's a good way to build a huge car-editor?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, it seems a good candidate for the use of composition. A car has: 
* wheels
* engine
* etc..

Each of these "domain objects" compose a car and have their own specific characteristics. I think you can probably split your code like this and do the same for each domain model if necessary.

Comment: Are you talking about "composed_of"? How would I then take i 5 steps further? 

composed_of :wheels, :mapping => %w(rim_size, rimtype, rimcolor, tyre-color)

Can I then call for instance <% f.select :rim_size  [['15'], ['16'], ['17']] %> 

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods/composed_of

Comment: What about outputting? I'd still have to loop through everything to find the correct settings? Or? I tried googling this and read that in PHP, many if statements can actually speed things up - I didn't find the answer relative to rails though. 1000 variables would practically mean 1000 if statements? Can't be good.

Comment: I am talking about model composition, in the `has_(many|one)` kind of relation. You could them use partials to split the "form" or use some kind of decorator. It seems kind of crazy to do it in a single class...

Comment: Oh right, regular associations.... I have counted and that would make 50 individual classes to cover all the main parts that I have in mind for my car editor which in my ear sounds pretty crazy as well. But let's say then for the sake of it that each corresponding view then is rendered in a master view and in each individual partial, I bring out all the if statements - Would that be "sufficient" you say? Could you say it's true with rails that the more you split things up in, the better? More smaller classes and modules rather than few large ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) and a jsonb db field as a possible starting point.  If you install the virtus gem, then you could set up a pseudo-model called something like CarSettings.  This would look something like:

```
class CarSettings
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :steering_wheel_color, String, default: ''
  attribute :gear_box_knob, String, default: ''
  attribute :has_spoiler, Boolean, default: false
  ...

  def self.dump(settings)
    settings.to_hash
  end

  def self.load(settings)
    new(settings)
  end
end
```

These settings then are serialized to/from json in your Car (or whatever) class like this:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  (stuff)
  serialize :settings, CarSettings
end
```

Then you can use standard RoR AR accessors to get to the settings:

```
car.settings.steering_wheel_color = ...
```

Not sure how you are planning to get steering_wheel_color from just booleans, but maybe you want to set up enums for the options for each "thing" and use dropdowns to present instead of checkboxes to present?  I've used the [classy_enum](https://github.com/AgilionApps/classy_enum) gem for this, but just regular enums would work as well.

**EDIT:**

Forgot some things you'll need in the Car model:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  attr_accessor :steering_wheel_color, :gear_box_knob, etc

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    self.settings.send(m, *args, &block)
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    names = CarSettings.attribute_set.map { |a| a.name }
    names.include? method_name
  end
end
```

In Rails 4.2, this was working without the attr_accessors, however, for some reason in Rails 5, it gives an unknown attribute error without the attr_accessors when trying to do .update_attributes(car_params).  Still trying to determine why that changed, but the attr_accessors work for now.

Comment: So, let's then take the example of "car.settings.steering_wheel_color = ..." Do you mean like <%= @ car.settings.steering_wheel_color %> and then the color is accessible through that variable instead of doing <%= if @ car.settings.steering_wheel_color == blue%> "show blue steeringwheel" %> <%end %>...?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I've been out of town for my job.  Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  IMHO, I think it would be a simpler approach to what you're trying to do (as far as my understanding of it goes).  Far fewer attribute permutations to deal with.

Comment: Just updated my answer with some methods I forgot to include that you'll need.

Comment: That's alright - I got it working anyways - It was an excellent solution. While you forgot to give me a reply, I forgot to mark your answer as the right one. Thanks!

I do have a question - I've been reading up on Fat models, slim controllers.  Why is it still a bad practice to have a lot of columns in a DB table? I read that this method still gives ActiveRecord the same amount of work to do... Is that true? Do you do this for performance reasons or for code-upkeep/management reasons?

Comment: It's more for maintainability/flexibility.  If you need to add a new attribute, you can just add it to the model without having to add fields to the db.  This is especially useful if you have many attributes on a model to keep track of.  While it CAN be done with table fields, I've found this approach much simpler to modify and maintain.  My understanding is that it's also faster over the pipe, but I don't personally have benchmarks to prove that.  As far as keeping your models thin, I think that's more about keeping logic out of them, not persistence code.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Chris, it does.